# Microsoft SQL Server 2017: Getting 300 Login Errors (18456, Severity 14, State 5) over 7 seconds when opening a Query in Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

My current project is troubleshooting our program and server performance and I got stuck on this:

Whenever I run a query in Access I get a massive amount of these errors in my log file:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
> Error message:
> Login failed for user 'Jakob'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <*named pipe*>]

Weirdly enough the query resolves normally (although maybe a little slowly) and I get the expected results But my goal remains to fix this issue for the sake of deepening my understanding of the SQL Server environment and to increase performance.

Here are all the information I have gathered:

1. A lot of these errors occur, when opening a query and I get 1 to 2 of these errors when opening the 3 integrated tables in rapid succession. (Not when I open just 1 of them)
2. I have integrated 3 tables from the SQL Server on my local machine via ODBC with the following code:

   ```
   Public Function ConnectTable(strTableName As String, strDateiname As String, Optional SQLSvrBo As Boolean = False, Optional strPreFix = "", Optional impBo As Boolean = False) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   Dim DB As Database
   Dim tdf As TableDef
       Set DB = CurrentDb
       DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strPreFix & strTableName

   On Error GoTo Err_ConnectTable
   If SQLSvrBo = False Then 'Connect to Access-Database'
           Set tdf = DB.CreateTableDef(strPreFix & strTableName)
           tdf.SourceTableName = strTableName

           tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strDateiname
           DB.TableDefs.Append tdf
           ConnectTable = True
   Else 'Connect to SQL-Server'
           Set tdf = DB.CreateTableDef(strPreFix & strTableName)
           tdf.SourceTableName = "dbo." & strTableName
           tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER={" & SQLODBCDriver() & "};SERVER=" & SQLServerName() & ";DATABASE=" & SQLDatabase() & ";UID=" & SQLUID() & ";PWD=" & SQLPassword() & ";APP=Microsoft® Access;[LOGINTIMEOUT=25;]"
           DB.TableDefs.Append tdf
           ConnectTable = True
   End If
   Exit Function

   'Error Handler'

   End Function
   ```
3. On the "Frontend" we have "Query 0" which joins a local Access table with "Query 1". "Query 1" joins two of the integrated tables. The third integrated table is manipulated via a RecordSet, which writes data into "Query 0" by using a function. This function gets called 3 times per row and loops (max 3 times) if there are more than 1 entry for the corresponding record. 
    *I have triple checked the Extended Events and there are exactly an equal number of SQL-Statements and Error Messages.*
4. I am running the newest versions of both MS Access and MS SQL-Server 2017 (EXPRESS) on my local machine, which has newest Windows 11 Updates installed.

### What I have tried:

1. I have disabled the Named Pipes with the SQL Server Configuration Manager to no success. The Error message still mentions [Client: <*named pipe*>]!
2. "Managed" (: to replicate it on another system. But I didn't change anything from my setup, the same errors just happened to also occur there.

My guess is, that it has something to do with Access trying to connect to SQL Server via both SQL Server Authentication (which is obviously working, thanks to my flawless Copy-Paste-Skills) **and** Windows Authentication.

Comment: No offence, but the personal details don't make the question clearer, they just add more to read. Short and concise is the best approach here.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - the user is missing. This has nothing to do with protocols or the operating system. Windows Authentication works fine. There's no reason to use a username and password on a Windows environment. Use the correct connection string and add your account to the SQL Server logins

Comment: It wasn't "butchered" i removed the noise, and some of the over emphasis of words (such as the overuse of **bold** text), and formatted your error.

Comment: Technically speaking, it's the `LOGIN` that's missing, @PanagiotisKanavos , which is an Instance object. There *might* be a `USER` called `jakob` in the database the OP is connecting to, but if there is, it's not mapped to the `LOGIN` `jakob` and the database isn't a contained database and using it's own security principles for authentication.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Some of our Clients dont use Windows as OS, which means we have to (and want to) use the SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: @JakobMöbius which means MacOS. Access only runs on Windows and Mac. The problem is still the missing login, not the protocols

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the help! And Sorry for the wording, first post so I didnt anticipate such a swift response, or that you could edit my post.

There is a user named SQ17\Jakob that I have assigned db_owner rights for the database in question.

Comment: `SQ17\Jakob` isn't a SQL Authentication `LOGIN`, @JakobMöbius, that's a Windows Credential. YOu can't use the a Windows Authentication `LOGIN` like a SQL Authentication `LOGIN`, and it especially won't work when the name is spell incorrectly (`SQ17\Jakob` <> `Jakob`). You need to create a separate SQL Authentication Login for SQL Authentication. The 2 methods are 2 completely separate ways of authenticating and they do not overlap. It's like going up to a door that has both a keypad and a keyhole, either of which open the door, and trying to put the key into the keypad; it won't work.

Comment: @Larnu But thats not the point, I want to use SQL Authenticatoin and I do also have a User with db_owner rights assigned, that I am using to connect (which is working).
Is there maybe a way to prevent Access from trying to also use Windows Authentication?
Because nowhere in my code have I specified to use Windows authentication.

Comment: *"But thats not the point"* Then why mention the windows `LOGIN` `SQ17\Jakob` if it's not relevant? The reason your connection, via SQL Authentication, is failing is because the `LOGIN` you are trying to use do *not* exist.

Comment: @Larnu The connection via SQL Authentication is working because the Login I am using does exist with db_owner rights! The Queries show the expected results!! The problem is: I did use the key to open the door, but the keypad is screeching: _"Open me!"_
How do I prevent the server from trying to also connect via Windows Authentication, when the SQL Server Authentication has already worked?

Comment: *Somewhere* in your Access code you are defining a `LOGIN` called `Jakob`, @JakobMöbius . We don't know where that is, we don't have that part of your code.

Comment: @Larnu No I do not. You can see the connection string in my code and I assure you, that I have called the right user with the function `SQLUID()`. For some reason Access just tries to connect via Windows Authentication anyways. Is there maybe a setting within Access or an attribute I can use in the connection string or something along those lines, that would prevent such behavior from Access?

Comment: So are you now asking about a different problem, @JakobMöbius ? The error you appear to ask about in your question is `Login failed for user 'Jakob'. `, which is in regards to a SQL Authentication Login (that doesn't exist). Are you also, therefore, getting failed logins for a Windows Login? That isn't covered in your question.